# Can't find the reason why root directory usage is so large

Tags: linux, rhel, disk-usage, lsof

Everyone. I have a very difficult thing to do. I have a *Linux* server, and the `root` directory has *16GB* of space.

- `df -h`, shows the `/` directory has been used for *15GB*, but
- `du -sh` shows that only *5.9GB* of space is used.
- the `lsof | grep deleted` command shows only *101KB* of space had not been released.
- Finally, `dumpe2fs` showed a lot of blocks in the root directory weren't used (near *9.4GB*).

I didn't know what was going on. Can you teach me what this is? This is a production server. Customers are not allowed to restart.

The directory following "*--exclude=*", which starts with  */i* and */p*, is the same thing as the two directories that start with a */i* and */p* in the results of `df -h`.

I've seen similar questions from other people, and I feel a little different.  The root directory near *9.4GB*'s block is not used, and there is only *101KB* of space not released, so I think it's different from other people's questions, although their situation is a little similar to mine, Please don't label my questions with duplicate.

[image: <code>df -h</code> , <code>du -sh</code> and <code>lsof | grep deleted</code> result]

[image: number of free blocks on /]

Comment: You should avoid terminal screenshots and paste the data as code (i.e. indented with four spaces).

Comment: @reviewers: I vote to reopen this question because IMHO the situation is indeed different from the "duplicates" and the answers there do not solve this problem.

Comment: @ Hauke Laging Thank you for your reply. Next time I will pay attention not to post the terminal screenshots, write the code directly

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro I want to ask why do you think my question has been repeated with others? I have seen questions asked by other people, as well as responses from netizens. I took a look at the response from some netizens who said that some of the files might have been deleted, but it was used according to the program until it quit But in my question, I made it clear that I was using lsof grep delete to look up files that had not been released, and the result was that only 100KB had not been released, so I didn't think their responses could explain my problem.